# What is the difference between using pointer vector or non pointer vector?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
private:
    vector<float*>  m_values;
    vector<float> *m_index;
    vector<float*> *m_rowptr;
```

What would be the best way to save a large data structure, using vectors?

Comment: Define ‘best’...

Comment: Might as well just ask what a pointer is. What are you trying to do, and which book are you using?

Comment: `vector<float>  m_values` should be your go to unless profiling/benchmarking tells you need something else.

Comment: *a large data structure* -- `float` is not a "large data structure".  So your question is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The way to store a large quantity of floats is:

```
vector<float> m_index;
```

The vector manages the block of floats for you.

Making a pointer to the vector is pointless (hah!).

Making a vector of pointers is (usually*) not correct for your task, and it introduces a host of performance problems.

Making both things a pointer combines the two problems.

---

* Depending what you mean by "index", this may be one of those times. If you want a vector of "pointers to float", then make that thing.